# Suggestions for building legacy product patches after upgrading to TFS 2012

Tags: .net, tfs, .net-4.5

We're looking at upgrading our TFS 2010 server to TFS 2012. As I understand it, this requires upgrading the build servers to TFS 2012 too. Unfortunately it seems that installing the TFS 2012 build server causes .NET 4.5 to be installed. .NET 4.5 is an in-place upgrade of .NET 4.0 and hence all .NET 4.0 components, including the C# compiler, are replaced when it is installed. I do not wish to do this on the build server that is responsible for building patches of our established legacy products - we don't have the resources to fully test that building with the .NET 4.5 compiler/framework will not cause an issues when up until now they have always been built with .NET 4.0 components, and I've seen a number of posts online suggesting that moving from .NET 4.0 to 4.5 can cause compilations to break.
At this stage I only see two options:
a) Maintain a separate TFS 2010 system just for building the legacy product.
b) Don't use a build server to build the patches (execute msbuild manually against the build definition from a machine with just .NET 4.0/VS 2010 - assuming that's possible?)

Any suggestions welcome!

(Edit: did a little reading and I don't see any straightforward way of executing build from a build definition/build process file from a command-line: yes there's tfsbuild but that just tells TFS build server to build it. It might be somehow possible using Windows Workflow foundation command line tools but it's hard to see how. More likely I'd have to rewrite the build script as some sort of batch file that calls msbuild to build the solution then calls other tools as needed to build/sign the installer and copy to the required location.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of TFS 2012 update 2 you can [continue to use TFS 2010 build agents](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2013/03/30/team-foundation-server-2012-update-2-supports-2010-build-agents-and-controllers.aspx). So you can continue to build your .net 4.0 code without worrying about compatibility with 4.5

Comment: Thank you! Will definitely investigate.

Comment: We've installed Update 2 and confirmed that you can attach TFS 2010 build agents, but I'm stuck as to whether you can use custom activity assemblies compiled for TFS 2010 (using VS 2010) on TFS 2012 build servers - basically we need both 2010 and 2012 build servers (for building separate products) but would hope to use the same custom activity assemblies. I'm currently getting an error "Could not load type 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.BuildMessage' from assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

Comment: (cont) Note that I actually got this error initially using the custom activity built under VS 2012 linked against the TFS 2012 (version 11.0.0.0) assemblies, then rolled back to the old version, ensuring the newer version was purged from my system completely (checked the GAC, restarted all services) but still get the same error.  I wrote a simple console app to emulate calling the custom build activity and it works fine. Tried attaching the debugger to the TFS build service process but no luck.

Comment: FWIW, the only way I was eventually able to solve this is to remove any reference to this type, and use the TrackBuildMessage extension function instead. Using this I can confirm that a custom activity assembly built for TFS 2010 will work under a TFS 2012 (update 2) server.